# Power apps visible text

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, powerapp, formula, powerapps-canvas

I'd like to make text disappear when dropdown selection is not equal to "Please Select".

Using formula:

```
IsBlank(if(Dropdown1_1.Selected.Site <> "Please Select"))
```

This is giving me error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to hide the **label** control text based on dropdown selection?

Comment: Ganesh, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `visible` property of label control to:

```
Not(Dropdown1_1.Selected.Site <> "Please Select")
```

**Update from comments**:

As @RobertLindgren suggested, below should also work for you:

```
Dropdown1_1.Selected.Site = "Please Select"
```

Comment: Ganesh , thanks for your support.

Comment: Or
`Dropdown1_1.Selected.Site = "Please Select"`
I guess

Comment: @RobertLindgren Yes, that should work too!